# Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch : Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nodejs

I received the topic error when starting the react app in the VS Code terminal. I have seen the answers to the topic questions as below.

Temporary Fix:

```bash
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sudo sysctl -p
```

Permanent Fix:

```bash
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

1. What actually causes this error? Because I got this when tried to run the app on the next day, which I already ran it yesterday without any problem with the same files?
2. Is it possible to occur this other than node modules in Ubuntu?
3. If we set this figure, it consumes memory. Is it possible to revert it back to default 8192 again? If not possible, is it limitation in Ubuntu, which need to be addressed in future releases?

Answer (score 5):

1. See this answer on [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502812) (not mine)

I suspect the watches from the previous day are still in effect.

2. It can happen anytime you run out of instances or watches.  See previous link.  User Oligofren's script and explaination is excellent.
3. Killing the watching process should work.  On my machine exiting VS Code freed up ~470 watches.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe that at least theoretically the error appears when there are too many files watched at the same time.

   If You want to know how many files are being watched by which process an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/whos-consuming-my-inotify-resources/502812#502812) linked in an [answer by @VXDguy](https://askubuntu.com/a/1369321/59600) contains a [link](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers) to a more complex script which should also display specific "INOTIFY WATCHER COUNT".

   On the other hand if You just want to see a list of processes which watch for some file changes You can use the following I think:

   ```bash
   sudo ls -l /proc/*/fd/* | grep notify | ps -p $(perl -n -e'/\/proc\/(\d*)\/fd/ && print "$1\n"')
   ```

   (based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20355384/1505369 , with other help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957781/1505369 - thank You!).
   It doesn't show how many files are being watch though, so You can just guess which process is the main source of the issue.
2. Are You asking if application not connected with Node may affect the issue? If so, I believe yes, they can. I think this limit is not strictly Node-related but system-related.
3. I believe You can go back to a default limit just by manually editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and removing or commenting out a line containing "fs.inotify.max_user_watches" and then running `sudo sysctl -p`.

   I also believe You can also just set the default value with modified version of the command You Yourself posted (I would recommend the first solution to not make `/etc/sysctl.conf` "polluted" though):

   ```bash
   echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=8192 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   sudo sysctl -p
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Changing system settings to insane values is a bad idea, so the sysctl stuff mentioned above is at most a bad 'workaround' but not at all a 'fix'.

A fix would be to configure the related application to do not such non-sense like watching the whole filesystem etc.. E.g. for VScode one may add a `files.watcherExclude` property to `${HOME}/.config/Code/User/settings.json`, so that it looks like this:

```json
{
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/.git/objects": true,
        "**/.git/subtree-cache": true,
        "**/.nfs*": true,
        "**/*.swp": true,
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/.next": true
    }
    /* ... other settings */
}
```

Unfortunately recent versions (e.g. 1.79.2) are buggy and do not honor it anymore.

Similar in NextJS projects root folder one may add to the project's `next.config.js` similar settings like this:

```javascript
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack: function (config, options) {
        if (!config.watchOptions) {
            config.watchOptions = {
                aggregateTimeout: 5,
                //followSymlinks: false,
                ignored: [ '**/node_modules', '**/.git/**', '**/.next/**' ]
            };
        }
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/i,
            issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
            use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
        })
        return config;
    },
    experimental: {
        /* appDir: true, */
        instrumentationHook: true
    }
};
/*
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    console.log('unhandledRejection', error);
});
*/
module.exports = nextConfig
```

Only if there is no known way to fix the app, one should open a ticket/create a new issue on the related repository and increase system settings as needed (i.e. try with 16K first ...) 'til the app vendor has fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

from : https://github.com/guard/listen/blob/master/README.md

do this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sysctl -p
```